# How to backup VM from bhyve and migrate it to KVM?

Tags: kvm, migration, bhyve

I am stuck here and can not find information about migrating Windows and Linux/Unix vm's to KVM. Doing it with zfs is inefficient, because it will transfer the whole disk space, which can be more than 200GB.

Making a copy of the directories in Linux/Unix machines kind of worked, but I don't think that's the right way.

```
cp -R /etc
cp -R /home/user
And send those copies to the KVM machine.
```

For the Linux part was basically that. I needed mainly installed services and their configs. If there is a way to copy the entire VM and spin it up on KVM good, I am open.

Creating a backup of Windows Server does not work also, because it creates vhdx files and converting them to qcow2 seems to break them, or I just don't do it right.

```
I use the Backup service and add the whole system backup zip to a network share. Basically that's it and I am stuck how it can but used to spin up new Windows VM on KVM.
```

Can someone give me guidance here?

Comment: "doing with with ZFS is inefficient, because it will transfer the whole disk space": um, no? ZFS `send` and `receive` will only copy used extents. So, maybe you're doing something else?

Comment: "I don't think that's the right way." Why not? What's the reason you think this? You might have requirements that say it isn't, but we don't know your requirements!

Comment: "or I just don't do it right." this one kind of directly says you should tell us, in verbatim commands, what you're doing.

Comment: Let me update it.

Comment: Explained what I have done, there is nothing more than that for now.

Comment: hm, so you've not tried to make ZFS backups? In that case, try that. As said above, it's pretty painless and fast.

Comment: @MarcusMüller do you have the steps necessary for spinning it up from ZFS dataset? I've copied it to the KVM host.